# Изменение значения поля объекта по его имени

Tags: java, рефлексия

Есть такой код:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class CBFIni {

        public ArrayList<SectionFields> sectionData = new ArrayList<SectionFields>();
        Pattern patternParam = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z_0-9]+");
        Matcher matchParam, matchValue;
        String nameParam;

        public CBFIni() {

                try {

                        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("backups.conf"));
                        boolean checkSection = false;
                        int i = -1;

                        for(String line: lines){
                                if (line.length() > 0 && line.charAt(0) != '#') {
                                        if (!checkSection) {
                                                checkSection = true; // Отметка, что начались параметры секции
                                                sectionData.add(new SectionFields()); // Создаем новый элемент-объект списка
                                        }
                                        i++;
                                        matchParam = patternParam.matcher(line); // Выуживаем имя параметра
                                        if (matchParam.matches()) {
                                                nameParam = line.substring(matchParam.start(),matchParam.end()); // Имя параметра
                                                sectionData.get(sectionData.size()-1).(nameParam) = line.substring(matchParam.end()+1);
                                        }
                                } else {
                                        checkSection = false;
                                        i = -1;
                                }
                        }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                } 
        }

        public class SectionFields {
                String backup, description, type, server, folder;
                int days, weeks, monthes, years, masterDay;
        }

}
```

Что надо писать в строке

```
sectionData.get(sectionData.size()-1).(nameParam) = line.substring(matchParam.end()+1);
```

вместо (nameParam), чтобы сослаться на поле объекта в списке?

Comment: копайте в сторону рефлекшенов: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько подходов.

Можно воспользоваться *[Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)* :

```
private static void setValue(Class<?> type, 
                             Object object, 
                             String paramName, 
                             String value) throws Exception {

    Field field;
    do {
        field = type.getDeclaredField(paramName);
        type = type.getSuperclass();
    } while (field != null && type != null);

    if (field == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                          "can't find the field with name: " + paramName);

    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(object, value);
}
```

Либо  *[MethodHandlers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html)*, что будет быстрее при неоднократном присваении:

```
private static Map<String, MethodHandle> getSetters(Class<?> type) throws Exception {
    Map<String, MethodHandle> setters = new HashMap<>();
    while (type != null) {
        for (Field field : type.getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            setters.put(field.getName(), MethodHandles
                                                      .lookup()
                                                      .unreflectSetter(field));
        }
        type = type.getSuperclass();
    }

    return setters;
}
```

Изменение значения, будет выглядить следующим образом:

```
Map<String, MethodHandle> setters = getSetters(SectionFields.class);
SectionFields obj = new SectionFields();
setters.get("backup").invoke(obj, "hello world");
```

Comment: Всё работает (выбрал второй вариант). Только в классе **SectionFields** мне пришлось объявить все поля как **String**, от **int** пришлось отказаться. Наверно, это решаемо (как-то проверять тип), но пока оставил так.